# How do I take an input string and count the number of characters in it by maintaining the order?

Tags: python, string, count

```
my_string = "aaabbcccaa"
required_output = "a3b2c3a2"
```

Please do not provide the code, I would like to try it myself, Please suggest me an approach with which i can get the required output.

As suggested by @ggradnig I've tried the below code.

```
 def count_string(s):
    current_char= s[0]
    counter =0
    result_string = ''
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == current_char:
            counter+=1  
        if s[i] != current_char:
            result_string=result_string+current_char+str(counter)
            current_char = s[i]
            counter = 1
            continue
    result_string=result_string+current_char+str(counter)   


    return result_string

given_string=count_string("aabbbccccaa")
print(given_string)
```

Please suggest changes to improve the above code

Comment: How would you, a human being, do it with a pencil and a piece of paper?

Comment: Think of a way you want to keep track of each "unique" letter, and how many times they come up. There is a specific data structure you can use for this.

Comment: Doing it with pencil and a piece of paper, was easy.Coding the same in python is difficult.

Comment: Check out the [str.count()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable for the current character you are counting and a counter variable. Set the "current character" to the first character of the string and the counter to 0. Also, declare an empty result String.

Now iterate over each character of the input String and check if it equals your "current character". If no, append this character to your result String, followed by the current value of the counter. Also, set the counter to 1 after appending and the "current character" to the character you are currently iterating over (i.e. the next character). If the character your currently iterating equals your "current character", increase your counter.

Comment: can you please suggest changes to the code I've written.

Answer (score 0):

Use hashing.. with dictionaries in python. Make the character key and its occurrence a value.. And then traverse the dictionary... and took a empty string and append the both key and its value to the string.

**EDIT**

Now i think to change my approach instead of using sets under Dictionary and making things complex we can use simple approach. This program is working.

```
string2=""
string=input()
i=0
while(i<len(string)):
    count=1
    for j in range(i+1,len(string)):
        if string[i]==string[j]:
            count+=1
        else:
            break
    string2=string2+string[i]
    string2=string2+str(count)
    i=i+count
print(string2)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you end up with `'a5b2c3'` following this logic (or just as likely `'b2a5c3'`, etc.) which is *not* what the OP desires?  How do you keep the two runs of 'a' separate in a hashing scheme and/or preserve the order of events?

Comment: If this help you then please let me know.

Comment: It helps in that it confirms my two assertions that a dictionary isn't the way to solve this problem and that `str.count()` isn't useful either.

Comment: Is there any time complexity constraints

Answer (score 0):

***my_string = "aaabbcccaa" required_output= a3b2c3a2***

You are counting consecutive characters, if the subsequent character is same, you increment a count variable, if the subsequent char is different, you move on and reinitialize count variable. Append count to the encountered character. When appending integer to a string you will have to typecast. Time complexity is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

The function `groupby()` in the module **itertools** makes this trivial.  Read it's documentation where it shows the example (in comments):

```
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')]
[['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], ['B', 'B', 'B'], ['C', 'C'], ['D']]
```

From here you simply combine the first element of each sublist with the length of that sublist and you have your answer.  Some string conversion and joining lists on empty strings necessary but basically a one-liner.

I don't understand why folks recommend the `str.count()` method. It combines two 'a' runs into one count which isn't desired and once you've broken the string into same letter substrings, `len()` can do the job.

> Please suggest changes to improve the above code

```
from itertools import groupby

string = 'aaabbcccaa'

def count_string(s):

    return ''.join(x[0] + str(len(x)) for x in (list(g) for _, g in groupby(s)))

print(string, '->', count_string(string))
```

Or if you wish to stay with your current algorithm, I suggest at least the following code cleanup:

```
def count_string(s):
    counter = 0
    result_string = ''
    current_char = s[0]

    for c in s:
        if c == current_char:
            counter += 1
        else:
            result_string += current_char + str(counter)
            current_char = c
            counter = 1

    return result_string + current_char + str(counter)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a for loop and string "count" method

and if you want me to post the code also tell me

Comment: but i'm able to get to the output :'a5b2c3'
but am not able to separate out the a's. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Python has two method that you might fine useful.
I think python has count method that you could use or there is a length method  that  you can pass your string to and it out the length of the string.